# How i can change and run sql file into mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have my database in sqlite .I exported sql file from sqlite manager. Now on executing that file into Microsoft SQL Server 2012 it is giving error on following lines.

```
DROP TABLE

IF EXISTS "Admin";
    CREATE TABLE "AdvancePayments" (
        "Id" INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        "date" VARCHAR,
        "Name" VARCHAR,
        "Amount" INT,
        "Remarks" VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO "AdvancePayments"
VALUES (
    1,
    '11/22/2013',
    'wqqw',
    21,
    'fgdsr');

CREATE TABLE "DVouchers" (
    "DVid" INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "vdate" VARCHAR DEFAULT(NULL),
    "Vehiclenum" VARCHAR,
    "Coupen" BOOL,
    "Saleperson" VARCHAR,
    "DVnumber" INT,
    "Ares" VARCHAR,
    "Ctitle" VARCHAR,
    "remarks" VARCHAR,
    "mEntry" BOOL,
    "Cust_Id" INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (Cust_Id) REFERENCES Customer_New(Cust_Id));
```

What is correct syntax for mssql?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: The correct syntax for SQL Server is documented in the manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it as:

```
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Admin;
--query to drop a table
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableName]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[TableName]
GO

CREATE TABLE [AdvancePayments] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,--The MS SQL Server uses the IDENTITY keyword to perform an auto-increment feature
    [date] VARCHAR(10),-- best practice is to use datetime datatype to store date feilds.
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    [Amount] INT,
    [Remarks] VARCHAR(1000)
);

INSERT INTO AdvancePayments
VALUES (
    --1,-- you cannot give an explicit value to identity column untill IDENTITY_INSERT is ON. So comment this.
    '11/22/2013',
    'wqqw',
    21,
    'fgdsr');

CREATE TABLE [DVouchers] (
    [DVid] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [vdate] VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT(NULL),
    [Vehiclenum] VARCHAR(100),
    [Coupen] BIT,-- Bit is the datatype used for Boolean values.
    [Saleperson] VARCHAR(100),
    [DVnumber] INT,
    [Ares] VARCHAR(100),
    [Ctitle] VARCHAR(100),
    [remarks] VARCHAR(100),
    [mEntry] BIT,
    [Cust_Id] INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (Cust_Id) REFERENCES Customer_New(Cust_Id)
    );
```

*Note: In MS SQL default length of varchar datatype is 1. so you will have to specify length to each 
varchar variable.*

Answer (score 0):

TSQL:

```
IF NOT OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableToDrop') IS NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE dbo.TableToDrop
END;
```

// change dbo. to your schema if necessary